# How to identify when i press any TextView array and load image to this i press

Tags: android

i have array of

```
public static TextView BB[] = new TextView[9];
```

How to identify when i press any TextView and load image to this i press

i clear all TextView like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
   BB[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.o);
}
```

maybe something like this ??

```
for(int i = 0; i< BB.length; i++){
    BB[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
           //how to load image ??
           //??.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.o);
        }
    });
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i< BB.length; i++){
    BB[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v){
       //how to load image ??
       v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.o);
    }
  });
}
```